# Visual Automation using Tagui and Sikuli

Tags: javascript, java, sikuli, rpa, sikuli-x

I was trying to use tagui for RPA but visual automation does not seem to be working. For example when I put the following texts into a tag file:

```
click start-menu.png
type page.png as notepad[Enter]
```

The mouse should click on the windows logo, type notepad and hit enter. But when I try to do it, it shows the following errors:

[image: error message on CMD]

[image: Another error message at the same time]

why is this error happening?

[image: start-menu.png]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your tagui installation is broken. You need to add correct tag to you question based on the tool you are using.

If you was using sikuli only I would say you need jython installer